# How do I figure out the correct argument structure for an unmanaged dll?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, vb6-migration, wininet

I was loading in some old VB functions from VBA, and mostly got everything updated to VB.NET, but there are function declarations for functions in "wininet.dll" which don't seem to match up correctly.

The Error I'm getting is:

> Exception Thrown: Managed Debugging Assistant, 'PInvokeStackImbalance':...

The long and short of it is that the length of the declared arguments needs to be explicit and it isn't matching up to the real functions in the dll.

I looked this up and I can get by just removing the checks, but it will have a "stack imbalance" and eventually eat up all the stack over time as these calls are made.  Also, these are called "unmanaged" dlls, and some declarations have been put up on a PInvoke function wiki at http://pinvoke.net. This wiki does have some of the function calls I'm using, but not all of them.  A few of them I had to guess at some things, and that didn't work out.

Most of the changes from what I copied from the older code were changing from `long` to `int32` or `integer`, and a few changes to `IntPtr`, which was never used in the old code.  I assume this gets all the integer sizes correct (i.e. 16/32/64 bits), which is probably where most of the problems were.  One case though, was a change from `long` to `string()`, which seems a bit odd and didn't compile okay.

**So, how do I actually look up the function lengths in the dll and match the API?**

I looked up a few things, but when I try to add a reference to c:\windows\system32\wininet.dll to my VB.NET project in Visual Studio, it says I can't add it. This appears to stop me from being able to use the Object or Assembly browser in Visual Studio.  It doesn't appear to be a COM object.  Any help here?

For reference, here's the old code that is failing:

```
Private Declare Function InternetOpen Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" ( _
    ByVal Agent As String, ByVal AccessType As Long, ByVal ProxyName As String, _
    ByVal ProxyBypass As String, ByVal Flags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetConnect Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetConnectA" ( _
    ByVal hInternetSession As Long, ByVal ServerName As String, ByVal ServerPort As Integer, ByVal UserName As String, _
    ByVal Password As String, ByVal Service As Long, ByVal Flags As Long, ByVal Context As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hInet As Long) As Boolean

Private Declare Function InternetReadFile Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hConnect As Long, ByVal Buffer As String, ByVal NumberOfBytesToRead As Long, _
    NumberOfBytesRead As Long) As Boolean

Private Declare Function HttpOpenRequest Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "HttpOpenRequestA" ( _
    ByVal hHttpSession As Long, ByVal Verb As String, ByVal ObjectName As String, ByVal Version As String, _
    ByVal Referer As String, ByVal AcceptTypes As Long, ByVal Flags As Long, Context As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function HttpSendRequest Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "HttpSendRequestA" ( _
    ByVal hHttpRequest As Long, ByVal Headers As String, ByVal HeadersLength As Long, _
    ByVal sOptional As String, ByVal OptionalLength As Long) As Boolean
```

Comment: Compare to the MSDN declaration for these functions.  DWORD is Integer and  HINTERNET is IntPtr.  And do retire these, you should be using WebClient and WebRequest.

Comment: @HansPassant I am planning on reimplementing these in a newer framework, but first I'd like to get the old code working - it's so close.  If for nothing else then understanding issues like this better and to learn.  **Regarding the MSDN declarations:** Where do I find those?

Comment: At MSDN.  Or Google, from their first hit.

Comment: Got it, thanks - now I need to dig into the differences between C++ declarations and VB, I guess, they only give the C++.  At least they have the `InternetReadFile` function that <http://pinvoke.net> didn't even have.

Comment: @HansPassant : Just a minor correction: `DWORD` is mapped to a `UInteger`, not a regular `Integer`. A `DWORD` has the range 0 - 4294967295.

Comment: @Visual - it is not, using Integer is often the better choice.  Knowing exactly when it is appropriate to lie, well, that's why pinvoke questions at SO never stop.

Comment: @HansPassant : Why is using an `Integer` better? The docs states both the range and declaration of a `DWORD` (**`unsigned long`**). Though since both takes 4 bytes of memory, does it really make a difference?

Comment: @LightCC : Thanks to David Heffernan I made some corrections to the table. See the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46547553/revisions) for information on what I've changed.

Comment: Yeah, the answer and comments here worked great to get what I think should have worked for these interfaces, but I never did get the functions built on top of them fully working.  My plan is to just convert the http part of the script to modern libraries when I get back to this - but hopefully the answers will help others in the future..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already [noted by Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539039/how-do-i-figure-out-the-correct-argument-structure-for-an-unmanaged-dll#comment80032739_46539039) you should use the managed alternatives instead.

However to answer your actual question: You basically just need to check the MSDN documentation article [***Windows Data Types***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx), and based on a type's declaration determine the respective .NET type.

For instance, a `DWORD`:

> **DWORD**
>   A 32-bit unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 4294967295 decimal.
>
> This type is declared in IntSafe.h as follows:
>
> `typedef unsigned long DWORD;`

In this case we can either go by the range (0 - 4294967295) or the definition (`unsigned long`) in order to determine that this should be an unsigned 32-bit integer (`UInt32` or `UInteger`). In C/C++ a `long` is the same thing as an `int`, which is why it's mapped to an integer and not the `Long/ULong`.

Here's a summary of the most common types:

*(Big thanks to [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088) for helping me correct some of the string declarations!)*

```
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|   Windows Type   |                   .NET equivalent                    |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| BOOL             | <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean  (vb.net)    |
| BOOL             | [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool     (c#)        |
| BYTE             | Byte   / Byte     (vb.net) / byte  (c#)              |
| CHAR             | Char   / Char     (vb.net) / char  (c#)              |
| DWORD            | UInt32 / UInteger (vb.net) / uint  (c#)              |
| DWORDLONG        | UInt64 / ULong    (vb.net) / ulong (c#)              |
| DWORD_PTR        | UIntPtr                                              |
| FLOAT            | Single / Single   (vb.net) / float (c#)              |
|                  |                                                      |
| HANDLE           | IntPtr                                               |
| HBITMAP          | IntPtr                                               |
| HCURSOR          | IntPtr                                               |
| HDESK            | IntPtr                                               |
| HDC              | IntPtr                                               |
| HICON            | IntPtr                                               |
| HINSTANCE        | IntPtr                                               |
| HRESULT          | Int32 / Integer (vb.net) / int (c#)                  |
| HWND             | IntPtr                                               |
|                  |                                                      |
| INT              | Int32 / Integer (vb.net) / int (c#)                  |
| INT_PTR          | IntPtr                                               |
| INT8             | SByte                                                |
| INT16            | Int16 / Short   (vb.net) / short (c#)                |
| INT32            | Int32 / Integer (vb.net) / int   (c#)                |
| INT64            | Int64 / Long    (vb.net) / long  (c#)                |
| LONG             | Int32 / Integer (vb.net) / int   (c#)                |
| LONGLONG         | Int64 / Long    (vb.net) / long  (c#)                |
| LONG_PTR         | IntPtr                                               |
| LPARAM           | IntPtr                                               |
|                  |                                                      |
| LPCSTR           | String (Specify CharSet.Ansi in DllImport)           |
| LPCTSTR          | String                                               |
| LPCWSTR          | String (Specify CharSet.Unicode in DllImport)        |
| LPDWORD          | (= DWORD,  declared as ByRef (vb.net) / ref (c#))    |
| LPHANDLE         | (= HANDLE, declared as ByRef (vb.net) / ref (c#))    |
| LPINT            | IntPtr                                               |
| LPLONG           | IntPtr                                               |
|                  |                                                      |
| LPSTR            | StringBuilder (Specify CharSet.Ansi in DllImport)    |
| LPTSTR           | StringBuilder                                        |
| LPVOID           | IntPtr                                               |
| LPWORD           | (= WORD, declared as ByRef (vb.net) / ref (c#))      |
| LPWSTR           | StringBuilder (Specify CharSet.Unicode in DllImport) |
|                  |                                                      |
| QWORD            | UInt64 / ULong (vb.net) / ulong (c#)                 |
| SHORT            | Int16  / Short (vb.net) / short (c#)                 |
| SIZE_T           | UIntPtr                                              |
| UCHAR            | Byte   / Byte    (vb.net) / byte (c#)                 |
| UINT             | UInt32 / UInteger (vb.net) / uint  (c#)                 |
| UINT_PTR         | IntPtr                                               |
| UINT8            | Byte   / Byte     (vb.net) / byte   (c#)             |
| UINT16           | UInt16 / UShort   (vb.net) / ushort (c#)             |
| UINT32           | UInt32 / UInteger (vb.net) / uint    (c#)             |
| UINT64           | UInt64 / ULong    (vb.net) / ulong   (c#)             |
| ULONG            | UInt32 / UInteger (vb.net) / uint    (c#)             |
| ULONGLONG        | UInt64 / ULong    (vb.net) / ulong   (c#)             |
| ULONG_PTR        | UIntPtr                                              |
| USHORT           | UInt16 / UShort   (vb.net) / ushort (c#)             |
| WORD             | UInt16 / UShort   (vb.net) / ushort (c#)             |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks - that table is the final piece needed.

Comment: @LightCC : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Comment: `LPCSTR` and `LPCWSTR` differ in their encoding. The former is `const char*`, the latter `const wchar_t*`. They both map to `string`. On the other hand `StringBuilder` maps to `char*` or `wchar_t*`, and their aliases `LPSTR` and `LPWSTR`.

Comment: A little. You are missing `LPCTSTR` and `LPSTR`. Your .net equivalent for `LPTSTR` is wrong, and that for `LPWSTR` is incomplete.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Strings are unfortunately one of the least I've worked with when P/Invoking ;). I hope the edits are correct! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Still better, but the non const variants LPSTR, LPWSTR, LPTSTR all map to StrngBuilder, but with the same CharSet riders as their const analogues

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : (Edited) Oh I see! So all non-constant `char/wchar_t` arrays map to `StringBuilder` because they can (sort of) be modified, but the `const` variants are immutable like the `String`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Thank you very much! You taught me something new, and very valuable, today!