# Create wrapper for c++ imported function in C#,Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, unmanaged

I have got c++ function with export looking like this:

`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LPCWSTR Function(void)`

But cannot get answer from it in vb.net.
Always get error that memory is corrupted.

I can alredy execute imported code like this:

`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Function2(wchar_t*)`

Can some one help with this?

#

Already found solution.

For my template it looks like:

```
    <DllImport(DllName)>
    Protected Shared Function Function() As IntPtr
    End Function

    Public Shared Function AliasForFunction() As String
        Return Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Function())
    End Function
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried in C# & vb.net - then maybe we can let you know how to correct it.

Comment: Is the c++ actually returning a LPCWSTR?

Comment: Yes, LPCWSTR. The test code in c++ is working. Looks like Label3->Caption=finction1();

Comment: How is the lifetime of the returned string managed?

Comment: An `LP(C)WSTR` is usually mapped to a `StringBuilder`. I made a table of some of the most common types here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547553/3740093

Comment: @VisualVincent No. `LPCWSTR` is mapped to `string`, with the appropriate encoding. Here we have a function return value, and `StringBuilder` can't be used in that setting anyway.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : You're right, my mistake.