# c dll works fine on vb6 but gives error on vb.net (Attempted to read or write protected memory)

Tags: string, vb.net, dll, vb6, dllimport

i have an old vb6 program that i need to use it on vb.net

i have been trying to fix this issue but could not get it fixed !
i have a dll file for reading and old rfdi card reader (RF20E its called)
i have managed it to work on reading cards but when it comes to sector reading it fails !
here is the function declaration from vb6

```
Declare Function rf_read_hex Lib "rf20e.dll" (ByVal icdev As Long, ByVal Adr%, ByVal sdata As String) As Integer
```

and here is the function call in vb6

```
Dim databuff32 As String * 32
address = 4
sector = 1
loadmode = 0

st = rf_authentication(ByVal icdev, loadmode, sector)
If st <> 0 Then
      M1_label.Caption = "Call rf_authentication() error.Exit!"
      Exit Sub
End If

st = rf_read_hex(ByVal icdev, address, databuff32)
If st <> 0 Then
     M1_label.Caption = "Call rf_read_hex error.Exit!"
     Exit Sub
End If
```

the above code works just fine

here is the .h library function

```
__int16 __stdcall rf_read_hex(HANDLE icdev,unsigned char _Adr, char *_Data);
```

but when i try to do the same in vb.net i get protected memory error

here is my code

```
Public Declare Function rf_read_hex Lib "rf20e.dll" (ByVal icdev As Integer, ByVal Adr%, ByRef sdata() As Char) As Short
    Dim sector As Integer = 1
    Dim address As Integer = 4
    Dim  loadmode = 0
    st = rf_authentication(icdev, loadmode, sector)                
    st2 = rf_read_hex(icdev, address, databuff32)
```

rf_authentication works fine !

i have tried different types of databuff32 -- byte char string but i am either getting type error or memory error !

however when i set type as : `Dim databuff32 As Char`  and in deceleration function set the reference as `ByRef sdata As Char` it works but !!!!! i can only read the first value nothing else

i am pretty sure the issue is that string * 32 deceleration but i could not fix it !

thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some more trying i have solved my problem !!!

here is the declaration that works:

```
Public Declare Function rf_read_hex Lib "rf20e.dll" (ByVal icdev As Integer, ByVal adr As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal sdata As StringBuilder) As Short
```

and here is the call:

```
Dim databuff32 As New StringBuilder(64)
st2 = rf_read_hex(icdev, address, databuff32)
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution, though `icdev` and `Adr` most definitely should be `IntPtr` and `Byte` (based on the C function).

Answer (score 2):

All your VB.NET parameters are incorrect. `icdev` should be an `IntPtr`, `Adr` should be a `Byte` and `sdata` should be `ByVal sdata As Char()` or `ByVal sdata As String`.

Also, in .NET you should use [**`DllImport`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `Declare ... Function`, as the latter only exists for backwards compatibility with VB6.

Try this:

```
<DllImport("rf20e.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Shared Function rf_read_hex(ByVal icdev As IntPtr, ByVal Adr As Byte, ByVal sdata As Char()) As Short
End Function
```

Refer to this answer of mine for a list of how you map certain Win32 types to .NET: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547553/3740093

Comment: thanks for the help but this wasnt my answer ! i have solved my problem   Public Declare Function rf_read_hex Lib "rf20e.dll" (ByVal icdev As Integer, ByVal adr As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal sdata As StringBuilder) As Short this was the answer and i declared databuff32 as new strgingbuilder(64) ans all is fine now