# Pass PByte to a DLL from vb..net

Tags: c++, arrays, vb.net, wrapper

I having troubles to calling a function inside a C DLL (dont know if C or C++)

Basically, I m trying to make a wrapper for the SDK DLL of Gigabyte RGB Fusion API.

I m working in VB.NET with Visual Studio 2013 (if you answer in C# is good too)

Declaring functions with DLLImport

for Ex. This function works fine.

C++

```
int  dllexp_GetMaxDivision(void)
```

VB.NET

```vb
<DllImport("GLedApi.dll", SetLastError:=False, callingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _

Public Shared Function dllexp_GetMaxDivision() As UInt32
EndFunction
```

calling `dllexp_GetMaxDivision` works like a charm. The trouble starts when i pass parameters:

```
DWORD  dllexp_GetLedLayout(PBYTE bytArray, int arySize)
```

> Parameters
>
> Name / Type / Description
>
> bytArray / Output / Pointer to a buffer that receives the LED layout on motherboard. The values of the elements in the array are as follows:
>   Value Meaning
>
> 0(NA) No implement LED
>
> 1(A_LED) Analog LED
>
> 2(D_LED_TYPE1) Digital LED Type 1
>
> 3(D_LED_TYPE2) Digital LED Type 2
>
> arySize / Input / Size, in byte of the buffer indicated by bytArray. This value must be a `dllexp_GetMaxDivision` return value.

```
DWORD  dllexp_SetLedData(PBYTE bytArray, int arySize)
```

> Parameters
>
> Name / Type / Description
>
> bytArray / Input / Pointer to a byte array converted from the LEDSETTING
>   structure array.
>
> arySize / Input / Size, in bytes, of the buffer indicated by bytArray.

```
typedef struct _LEDSETTING {
  BYTE  Reserve0;
  BYTE  LedMode;
  BYTE  MaxBrightness;
  BYTE  MinBrightness;
  DWORD dwColor;
  WORD  wTime0;
  WORD  wTime1;
  WORD  wTime2;
  BYTE  CtrlVal0;
  BYTE  CtrlVal1;
   }  LEDSETTING, *PLEDSETTING
```

This is what I try. I dont get to test with `dllexp_SetLedData` yet, so I will focus in `dllexp_GetLedLayout`

```vb
<DllImport("GLedApi.dll", setLastError:=False, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
    Public Shared Function dllexp_GetLedLayout(ByRef bytArray As IntPtr, arySize As Int32) As UInt32
End Function
```

Tried with a byte array, but didn't work. And This:

```vb
Dim Param(iMaxDivs - 1) As Byte
For A As Integer = 0 To iMaxDivs - 1
Param(A) = CByte(0)
Next


    Dim Tama As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(Param(0)) * Param.Length
    Dim buffer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Tama)
    Marshal.Copy(Param, 0, buffer, Param.Length)


    resp2 = GLed.dllexp_GetLedLayout(buffer, Param.Length)


    Marshal.Copy(buffer, Param, 0, Param.Length)  '<===== AccessViolationException

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer)
```

The line of code that retrieve the buffer to the array throw an exception:

> 'System.AccessViolationException' en mscorlib.dll Attempted to read or
>   write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory
>   is corrupt.

In some other tests, i had `PinvokeImbalance` sort of... , I guess it was a type mismatch.

The weird thing is that sometimes, the code doesnt throw an exception and proceed, but return the zero-filled array. even when the buffer contains data.

I also try with `AllocCoTaskMem` but the process crash...,

Can somebody please point me in the right way to do this??

Thanks!

Comment: For the record the return type of `dllexp_GetMaxDivision()` in VB.NET should be `Integer` or `Int32`, not `UInt32`.

Comment: Apart from that, a normal byte array should work. I'd try by declaring your function like: `Public Shared Function dllexp_GetLedLayout(ByVal bytArray As Byte(), arySize As Int32) As UInt32` then create a byte array with the size of the structure: `Dim Param(Marshal.SizeOf(LEDSETTING) - 1) As Byte`. Keep in mind that you must convert the `LEDSETTING` structure to VB.NET first.

Comment: Ok, @VisualVincent, `byval` worked! (i dont know how a byval param could retrieve data.. but it worked. )  
Regarding `dllexp_SetLedData`  I m lost on how to convert to a _byte array_. the `word` and `dword` data types (`Integer` and `Long`?) is giving me trouble. (*System.OverflowException* kind of trouble)  How can i convert that structure to a byte array??..  Thanks for your help!

Comment: All arrays are classes, and classes are what's called _Reference types_. Reference types are always passed _**By Reference**_ (ByRef). You don't retrieve any data, the function just fills an already existing array.

Comment: As for the data types: A `WORD` is a `UShort` and `DWORD` is a `UInteger`. See this answer of mine for a conversion table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547553/3740093

Comment: ok.. Now i m passing to SetLedData... is complex, so i posted in this 
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49092493/9408017)
Thanks for your help!!