# C++ DLL Wrapper in vb.net Passing byte array of a byte array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vb.net

I m calling a function, but i m stuck in the argument that i must pass:

this is what i got.

Function definition:

```
DWORD  dllexp_SetLedData(PBYTE bytArray, int arySize)
```

And this from the SDK:

> Parameters
>
> Name | Type | Description
>
> bytArray | Input | Pointer to a byte array converted from the LEDSETTING
>   structure array.
>   arySize | Input | Size, in bytes, of the buffer indicated by bytArray.
>
> Return Values 
>   Value | Description
>
> ERROR_SUCCESS(0x0) | Success 
>   ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION(0x10DD) | Fail

VB.NET

```vb
<DllImport("GLedApi.dll", setLastError:=False, callingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Shared Function dllexp_SetLedData(bytArray As Byte(), arySize As Int32) As Integer
End Function
```

Structure of LEDSETTING in C++

```
typedef struct tagLedSettingData {
   BYTE Reserve0;
   BYTE Mode_Sel;           //LED Mode
   BYTE MaxBrightness;      //default set to 100
   BYTE MinBrightness;      //defautl set to 0
   DWORD dwColor;          //0xWWRRGGBB, WW:0 -> WLED turn off, WW:0xFF -> WLED turn on
   WORD wTime_base0;      //light on time, in millisecond
   WORD wTime_base1;      //Interval time, in millisecond
   WORD wTime_base2;      //Cycle time, light on + light off <= Cycle time, this for Flash mode only
   BYTE CtrlVal0;
   BYTE CtrlVal1;
   } LedSettingData, *LedSettingData_Ptr;
```

Structure i wrote in vb.net

```vb
Public Structure GLEDSETTINGS
    Public Sub New(LedMod1 As ModeSelOptions, MaxB As Byte, MinB As Byte, dwColor1 As UInteger, aWtime0 As UShort, _
                   awtime1 As UShort, awtime2 As UShort, actrlVal0 As Byte, actrlVal1 As Byte)

        Reserved0 = &H0
        LedMod = LedMod1
        MaxBrightness = MaxB
        MinBrightness = MinB
        dwColor = dwColor1
        wTime0 = aWtime0
        wTime1 = awtime1
        wTime2 = awtime2
        CtrlVal0 = actrlVal0
        CtrlVal1 = actrlVal1

    End Sub

    Private Reserved0 As Byte
    Public LedMod As ModeSelOptions
    Public MaxBrightness As Byte  ' max 100
    Public MinBrightness As Byte
    Public dwColor As UInteger  ' &h0FFFFFF
    Public wTime0 As UShort
    Public wTime1 As UShort
    Public wTime2 As UShort
    Public CtrlVal0 As Byte
    Public CtrlVal1 As Byte

    Public Enum ModeSelOptions As Byte
        Defecto = 0
        Pulse
        Music
        ColorCycle
        Statico
        Flash
        Transition
        DigiModA
        DigiModB
        DigiModC
        DigiModD
        DigiModE
        DigiModF
        DigiModG
        DigiModH
        DigiModi
    End Enum
    Public Enum LedType As Integer
        NA
        A_LED
        D_LED_TYPE1
        D_LED_TYPE2
    End Enum

    Function ToByteArray() As Byte()

        Dim size As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(Me)
        Dim arr As Byte() = New Byte(size - 1) {}
        Dim ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size)
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(Me, ptr, True)
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr)
        Return arr

    End Function

End Structure
```

So far, so good, BUT... I think the function expect an array of byte array.. but i dont know how to do that in vb.net.

The only that i can do, is this:

```vb
Dim LD(iMaxDivs - 1) As GLEDSETTINGS

    For I = 0 To iMaxDivs - 1
        Dim L As New GLEDSETTINGS(GLEDSETTINGS.ModeSelOptions.Statico, 100, 0, &HFFFF11FFUI, 1000, 100, 0, &H0, &H0)
        LD(I) = L


    Next

    'Dim LDParam(LDTama) As Byte

    Dim LDTbrr As Byte() = LD(0).ToByteArray
    Dim LDTama As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(LD(0))


    resp3 = GLed.dllexp_SetLedData(LDTbrr, LDTama)
    Debug.WriteLine("SetLedData: " & resp3)
    If resp3 = GLed.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION Then
        Exit Sub

    End If
```

and i dont get an error, but `ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION`

I convert the structure in a byte array. with `ToByteArray` function in my structure, that works ok, but i cant put this array into a byte array as for example: `dim Array(10) as Byte()` is not allowed.

I saw this in the SDK C++ example of use of the DLL i m working with. but i can't "translate" it to vb.net.

```
pSettingData = new LedSettingData[iMaxDivs];
int dLen = iMaxDivs * sizeof(LedSettingData);
//ZeroMemory(pSettingData, dLen);

for (int i = 0; i < iMaxDivs; i++)
{
    (pSettingData + i)->Mode_Sel = sd.Mode_Sel;
    (pSettingData + i)->MaxBrightness = sd.MaxBrightness;
    (pSettingData + i)->MinBrightness = sd.MinBrightness;
    (pSettingData + i)->dwColor = sd.dwColor;
    (pSettingData + i)->wTime_base0 = sd.wTime_base0;
    (pSettingData + i)->wTime_base1 = sd.wTime_base1;
    (pSettingData + i)->wTime_base2 = sd.wTime_base2;
    (pSettingData + i)->CtrlVal0 = sd.CtrlVal0;
    (pSettingData + i)->CtrlVal1 = sd.CtrlVal1;
}

pfSetLedData((PBYTE)pSettingData, dLen);
```

Any light on this?.. Thank you very much!

Comment: Bizarre function, given that it is so much easier to use when it is declared correctly.  Which you can fix yourself, just declare the argument GLEDSETTING() instead of byte().  For the length argument pass Marshal.SizeOf(GLEDSETTING.GetType() * yourarr.Length).  Your structure declaration looks good, so this should just work without hassles.

Comment: You are right. This works too. 
I used `Marshal.SizeOf(LD(0).GetType) * LD.Length` for the second argument.and looks ok.
I think still something is out of line, becouse function works, but dont apply leds where it should be.. Still analyzing that..

Comment: Resolved.  weird function. Force me to "Apply" twice for correct functioning, but I m using your approuch. Thanks. @HansPassant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct. The C++ function expects a byte array of a `GLEDSETTINGS` array.

To convert the entire `GLEDSETTINGS` array into a byte array you have to create a new function and adapt your already existing code to work with a whole array instead.

For this I'd recommend creating an [**Extension method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods). Add a new `Module` to your project:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToByteArray(ByVal LedSettings As GLEDSETTINGS()) As Byte()
        Dim StructSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(GLEDSETTINGS))
        Dim Length As Integer = LedSettings.Length * StructSize 'The total amount of memory that our LedSettings array requires.
        Dim Bytes As Byte() = New Byte(Length - 1) {}
        Dim ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Length) 'Allocate a memory section for our data.

        'Iterate through every GLEDSETTINGS structure and put it in our memory section.
        For i = 0 To LedSettings.Length - 1
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(LedSettings(i), ptr + i * StructSize, True)
        Next

        Marshal.Copy(ptr, Bytes, 0, Length) 'Copy the data from our memory section into our byte array.
        Return Bytes
    End Function
End Module
```

Now you can call it like this:

```vb
Dim LDTbrr As Byte() = LD.ToByteArray()
resp3 = GLed.dllexp_SetLedData(LDTbrr, LDTbrr.Length)
```

Comment: Love the _extension_ method.  Really nice way to implement this.

Comment: I think still something is out of line, because function works, but dont apply leds where it should be.. Still analyzing that..

Comment: Resolved. Thank you very much!.,  You answer is the most accurate for what i request.

Comment: @MickMaister : Glad I could help! Good luck!